# Поток после воспроизведения медиафайла не закрывается

Tags: java

Возникла потребность воспроизвести аудио файлы в программе. Нашел на просторах интернета данный класс для воспроизведения аудио. Как я понял, он открывает новый поток, забрасывает в него аудио файл и воспроизводит его. Но после пару десятков таких запусков, количество оперативной памяти используемой программа, резко увеличивается. Есть подозрение что после окончания воспроизведения поток не закрывается. Как это исправить? С потоками пока еще не работал.

```
    import javax.sound.sampled.*;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class Audio {
        private String track;
        private Clip clip = null;
        private FloatControl volume = null;
        private double volumeValue;

        public Audio(String track, double volumeValue) {
            this.track = track;
            this.volumeValue = volumeValue;
        }

        public void sound() {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
            try {
                audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(track));
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();

            } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void setVolume() {
            if (volumeValue < 0) volumeValue = 0;
            if (volumeValue > 1) volumeValue = 1;
            float min = volume.getMinimum();
            float max = volume.getMaximum();
            volume.setValue((max - min) * (float) volumeValue + min);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Вызывайте `clip.close()` после окончания проигрывания. + можно это все поместить в `try with resources` конструкцию.

Comment: @Tsyklop если вызвать clip.close()  сразу после clip.start(); оно закроет проигрывание сразу же, не дождавшись конца проигрывания

Comment: так вызывайте после проигрывания.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
 public void sound() {
        try( AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(track)) ) {
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            clip.start();

        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь методом `addLineListener`:

```
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
    void update(LineEvent event) {
        if (event.getFramePosition() == clip.getFrameLength()) 
            clip.close();
    } 
});
```